# Styling text inside a property files

Tags: html, css, properties, internationalization

I'm using properties files in my webapp to cater i18n needs. Sometimes the text that I'm translating needs to have individual styling. For example:

```
options.reduce.co2.label = To reduce your CO2 emission, click here!
```

Should actually be rendered as:

```
To reduce your CO<span class="subscript">2</span> emission, <a href="www.blackle.com">click here</a>!
```

The diry fix would be to include this styling in my properties file. However, I really want to avoid this!

A more clean approach would be to split up all the parts of the text:

```
options.reduce.co2.label.part1 = To reduce your CO
options.reduce.co2.label.part2 = 2
options.reduce.co2.label.part3 = emission, 
options.reduce.co2.label.part4 = click here
options.reduce.co2.label.part5 = !
```

However, this makes the property files a big mess of words rather than structured sentences.

How do you generally deal with this situation? I want to achieve maximum readability and maintainability for the developers.

Comment: couldn't you just use an array?

Comment: How do arrays work inside property files?

Comment: I am not sure, i have never worked with webapps before ;) maybe something for you to look up and see if it is possible

Comment: In my opinion you should create a structural Json array!!!!! It´s easier, and for maintenance it´s the best option you can have. All you have to do is make your server code generate a Json file, for example.

Comment: The only proper way to do this is to include HTML tags in properties file. Despite the ugliness, it allows for: a) changing the order of the sentence (which is very common); b) removing styles that cannot be used due to cultural differences, or possibly changing them to something else. I tried to use markers instead of HTML tags, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Legues: JSON is not necessary the best format for translators and it is often not handled well by translation tools. From this point of view it is actually the format one should avoid. That is, unless you want to increase translation costs.

Answer (score 0):

I always use placeholders for this kind of stuff:

```
options.reduce.co2.label = To reduce your CO%s2%s emission, click %shere%s!
```

Comment: What is the syntax to fill in the %s parts in your jsp page?

Comment: I dont use jsp, so no idea, sorry

Comment: Well, i used the JSON panorama without any problems in a simple app. I found it easy to update/maintain. I just create some Json fragments and call them individually on language request!!!  @Paweł Dyda - What translation costs?